# File browser out of memory

Tags: android, video, bitmap, icons, out-of-memory

I am trying to load the thumbnails for videos in a file browser but its causing me to run out of memory.

```
public class Filea {

private Bitmap VideoIcon;

public Bitmap getVideoIcon() {
    return VideoIcon;
}

public void setVideoIcon(Bitmap videoIcon) {
    VideoIcon = videoIcon;
}
```

This is being done for every video file that is in a folder.

Every time that I load a new folder does it keep the information from the previous folder, and if so how do i get it to delete the unwanted resources?

```
private List<Filea> LoadFiles(String dirPath)  {
    inSearch = false;
    List<Filea> files = new ArrayList<Filea>();

    try {
    for(String F:EditedFileList(current)) {

       Filea file = new Filea();

    file.setVideoIcon(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(current + "/" + getName(F), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND));

       files.add(file);   
    }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        Log.i("LoadFiles", "No files found");
    }
    return files;
 }
```

This is how the information is obtained.

Along with the video thumbnails I am loading other bits of data E.g. File name, size, permissions, Image icons(as bitmaps) ect..

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're keeping around a bunch of unneeded references.  My suggestion would be to put the images in an LRUCache and load them from there.  That way you can set a reasonable maximum amount of memory to use on images.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i was trying to load the full image of picture instead of the thumbnails.`

```
               file.setImageIcon(ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(current + "/" + getName(F)), 100, 100));
```

Thank. LukeMovement.